# How to access DOM of a web page in QtWebKit?

Tags: c++, qt, dom, webkit, qtwebkit

How to access DOM of a web page in QtWebKit?
I don't see any methods exposing DOM in QtWebKit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now as of Qt 4.4/4.5 I don't think there are any direct way, but it's coming. See http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/04/07/qwebelement-sees-the-light-do-i-hear-a-booyakasha/

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you need to do DOM manipulation via JavaScript, injected via
    QVariant QWebFrame::evaluateJavaScript(const QString & scriptSource);

Answer (score 0):

the DOM manipulation via javascript method is incredibly poor.  for any serious usage it very quickly becomes apparent that it is completely unusable.  an experiment was made to create a runtime for pyjamas-desktop using pywebkitqt4 and it utterly, utterly failed.  quite a lot *was* achieved - such as event callbacks written in python - but they had to be set up... by creating a javascript code-snippet!  this approach is truly insane.  every time you want to manipulate the DOM model from python you have to go via a crap language like javascript?  anybody who thinks that's a good idea is completely off their heads.

fortunately at some point in the future i will be extending pythonwebkit to allow full access to DOM functions: it will be quite easy to do this, but i just don't have the time spare at the moment to compile up webkit for qt4 (it takes 90 mins for webkit with gtk as it is).